Instructions for assembly of slow close hinge set

So, I decided that, with a toddler in the house, I ought to set up slow close hinges on the toilet seat to reduce the amount of slamming involved. I ordered this set online, and it was cheap, but showed up without constructions. I think that I should be able to insert the seat onto those two silvery bits, and the other bolts are supposed to simply attach it to the toilet itself. However, it doesn't seem to actually turn, so I'm slightly iffy on whether these are actually the slow close hinges that they purport themselves to be. Does anybody recognize this particular setup for the components, and can give me some advice?

These look intended for a particular toilet seat. Do you have the toilet seat that these were designed for? If not, just buy a soft close seat. They are not so expensive anymore. There are replacement hinges that fit generically, but they are ugly, hard to install and expensive for what they are.

As for how to install these: Can you remove and lay out all the parts from the bag, and can you separate the shiny top part of the hinges from the white bottom part and show those separately?   And add a photo of your existing toilet seat hinges?

Why not just get a toilet seat that has a built-in slow close function?
